# Does WAP supports Android and IOS mobile operating system

Tags: mobile, wap

I want to start development on WAP..In initial findings i have found that

1. WAP is a communications protocol and application environment.
2. It can be built on any operating system including PalmOS, EPOC, Windows CE, FLEXOS, OS/9,
   JavaOS etc.
3. It provides service interoperability even between different device families.

What i want to know is Does it can be built on Android and IOS operating System?

Comment: Do you need to render WML markup or support all the old WAP technologies that never really took off?

Comment: @skaffman :: I am finding for WAP technology. I have a banking application requirement where i need to make that app specific to WAP..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two major WAP version.

WAP 1.x and WAP 2.0

WAP 1.x is old and obsolete. It can be built on Android. But no value. Because WAP 1.x client needs WAP 1.x gateway. But virtually all major operator stopped WAP gateway a couple years ago.

WAP 2.0 is current but becoming less meaning. Because most smartphone can support standrad web technology. It does not need less functional mobile version web technology.

The bottom line, if there is no WAP 1.x service in your country, any effort is pointless.